# Subjuctive Mood 1 and 2 with different markers of time

Tags: grammar, sentence-choice

Am I correct if I say?:

> 1. If I had not drunk coffee today I would have been sleepy.
> 2. If I didn't drink coffee today I would be sleepy.
> 3. If I had not already drunk coffee I would be sleepy now.
> 4. If I did not already drink coffee I would have been sleepy now.
> 5. If she hadn’t slept with him she wouldn’t become pregnant.
> 6. If she hadn’t slept with him she wouldn’t have become pregnant.

Answer (score 2):

"If you hadn't taken flight 903 yesterday, you wouldn't have landed late." This is a contrafactual statement about the past. You did take that flight yesterday and did land late as a consequence.

"If you didn't take flight 903 yesterday, you wouldn't have landed late." This is a conditional statement about the past. It neither affirms nor denies whether you took flight 903 yesterday or whether you landed late.

Your examples make obscure what is not overly complex in part because the time markers themselves in the examples are obscure and because past conditionals in the first person do not make much sense. But primarily, you are not distinguishing between conditional and counter-factual statements.

"If she hadn't drunk coffee this morning, she would have been sleepy long before now." A contrafactual about past action and past consequence. But she did drink coffee this morning.

"If she hadn't drunk coffee this morning, she would now be sleepy." A contrafactual about past action and present consequence. But she did drink coffee this morning.

The tense in the main clause of the contrafactual indicates whether we are talking about past or present consequence.

"If she didn't drink coffee this morning, she would have been sleepy long before now."

"If she didn't drink coffee this morning, she would be sleepy now."

These are conditional statements. The tense in the main clause indicates whether the consequence (if the conditional were true) was past or present.

"If she hadn't slept with him, she wouldn't have been pregnant." She did sleep with him, but the resulting pregnancy was in the past.

"If she hadn't slept with him, she wouldn't be pregnant." She did sleep with him, and the resulting pregnancy is in process.